# How do you determine the direction of AC current? (ex: whether your solar-powered house is drawing from the city power grid or adding to the grid)

Tags: ac

I'd like to measure the voltage and current of mains AC power at the fuse box where a house is connected to the grid. Assuming the house has solar panels on it, sometimes it will draw from the grid, and sometimes it will push to the grid. How can I measure the direction of AC current to determine which it is doing?

I plan on using a microcontroller to sample the AC waveform and do whatever math or RMS calculations I need to do once I understand what I need to do.

Comment: You read the output of your smart net-meter.  Even if you had an independent way to measure, what would matter is what the power company claimed.  If you are asking how an electric meter (especially a net meter) works, that's a valid question but one where you should start by showing some of your own research effort.

Answer (score 2):

This is considerably easier and safer if you interface to the existing meter that does this, but: your current measures will be signed. Positive or negative. Whether you're measuring through a shunt or magnetic methods. You need to compare to the sign of the voltage measured at the same time. Same sign means same phase opposite sign means out of phase. In phase should mean the grid is powering the house. Out of phase means the opposite.

Comment: Note that if your mains connection has 3 phases, this gets more complicated. Here where I live (eastern part of the EU) the utilities mandate a particular "set of evaluation rules" governing situations where the load between 3 phases (comprising your grid connection) is unevenly spread - or worse, where you consume on some phases and produce on other phases. And then there's the reactive component (phase shift) and how to deal with that... the SMPS converters in PV installations can help the grid balance the phase shift, even while there is no production or consumption... It's complicated.

Answer (score 1):

> *How can I measure the direction of AC current to determine which it is
> doing?*

You need to measure power (not current). Power flow will be positive if taking power from the grid and negative if putting power back to the grid. You need to implement a watt-meter circuit.

> *I'd like to measure the voltage and current of mains AC power at the
> fuse box where a house is connected to the grid.*

To measure power that is fine but it's probably more legal if you measure it after the utility power/energy meter. It won't make any real difference connecting the watt-meter after the utility meter.