# How do you combine 2 AC power sources?

Tags: ac, summing

To *combine 2 DC power sources*, you can diode OR them both together. You can't just directly connect them together because their voltage outputs may differ ever-so-slightly, leading to imbalanced currents as well, causing one generator to try and kill the other by driving current into it.

To *passively balance the two DC sources*, you can add 2 small (small resistance, high power) resistors, one in series with each of the loads, before or after the diode, before the junction of the two.

To *actively balance the two DC sources* you can use a microcontroller and control logic to PWM the side delivering more current until it delivers identical current to the side delivering less.

But...*how the heck do you combine two AC power sources?* It seems to me you'd have to synchronize the AC waveforms somehow. Let's look at solar panels on your roof. I hear some microinverters require "5 minutes to synchronize with your house mains power", meaning somehow, they are doing this. But how do you combine the two? If you put one AC wave from the house at 110V RMS on top of another AC wave from the solar panel at 110 V RMS, you'd **double the amplitude** to an RMS of 220 V, which seems wrong. If you put them out-of-phase you've just neutralized the AC mains power in your house, not added to it....so I don't get it. I have no idea how this works, how to approach the problem, or even how to conceptualize or think about the problem.

### Sort of adjacently-related:

1. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/515204/how-does-an-ac-circuit-get-anything-done
2. [How do you determine the direction of AC current? (ex: whether your solar-powered house is drawing from the city power grid or adding to the grid)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/507933/how-do-you-determine-the-direction-of-ac-current-ex-whether-your-solar-powere)

### Thought experiment (added 24 Oct. 2022)

From [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/637063/26234):

> The reason you don't get 220 V is that the incoming AC supply and the inverter(s) are wired in parallel, not series.

I think there's more to it than this. One way or another, the solar power needs to feed the grid. That requires a *voltage potential* *into* the grid.

As a thought experiment, if you put two 10 V voltage regulators in parallel, and they each output *exactly* 10 V, then the results will be 10 V. If the total current draw on that voltage output is 1 A, then each regulator will deliver 0.5 A, again, because they are *exactly balanced* in voltage in our hypothetical example. Now, to try to get one of them to deliver let's say 0.9 A and the other to deliver 0.1 A, you'd have to *try* to change their voltage output settings to make the 0.9 A one have lower resistance and a higher set-point on its voltage output.

So, to feed the AC grid I think you'd have to do the same: set a set-point slightly greater than the Vrms of the grid. I'd need to think this through some more and analyze it. I'll save that for future work another day. This feels like a multi-day problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110016/discussion-on-question-by-gabriel-staples-how-do-you-combine-2-ac-power-sources).

Answer (score 2):

You have answered your own question. The AC sources **MUST** be synchronized before merging using fuses plus low-ohm resistors and high-current inductors (to allow **slight** shifts in phase and voltage). **FIRST** you must verify with a 2 channel oscilloscope that they are in phase, and the same voltage and current rating. The fuses or breakers sourcing each AC supply **MUST** have the same rating.

This means that **separate AC sources need to come from the same breaker panel** to have any chance of being in phase. The other option (mentioned by Peter Bennett) is expensive grid-tied inverters that will sync to the grid first before connecting to it. This allows multiple sources to feed a common grid, but this is expensive application-specific hardware.

If NOT in phase another safe option is to convert both to DC, then use synchronous inverters or just sum the DC currents to drive a bigger inverter ( which will require its own high-current breaker on the outputs). This is a place where caution must dominate your decisions, or things may go BANG and you get hurt.

You **CAN** dependably connect 2 AC sources **IF** they are synchronous or can be made synchronous in a given time period. It is assumed both sources are at about the same voltage level and can supply matching currents from sources of similar impedance. Else you cannot just merge 2 AC sources without validating the requirements I just mentioned.

Unless you **NEED** to have a single source of high AC current (such as running a high-powered arc welder) you are better off with lower current AC sources with safe and legit-sized breakers. Breakers ONLY stop wires from catching fire, if they have correct ampere ratings.

If a AC source is weak and dynamic such as solar cells piped through an inverter, they cannot be merged with conventional AC source that is stable. Dynamic(and uncontrolled)AC sources cannot be summed together due to backfeed and driver issues, but DC sources can.

Comment: A grid-tied inverter is often used to feed solar-produced power to the grid.  Two independent AC sources can be combined if one source can be phase-controlled to remain in sync with the other source.

Comment: @Peterbennett I thought my first paragraph covered that issue, but I might have muddied the issue with too many paragraphs. Thanks for that important detail.

Comment: Yes, but then your second paragraph states that spearate AC sources must come from the same breakere panel, which disagrees with the first paragraph.

Comment: @Peterbennett I fixed that conundrum, and hope it is more clear.

Comment: No need for an oscilloscope. Incandescent lamps will do the trick very nicely. See my explanation here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/576412/73158.

Answer (score 2):

This issue comes up with power grid management. The short answer is, AC sources like generators must be carefully synchronized in voltage and phase prior to combining them. Once combined, the generators will tend to self-synchronize together. To work properly as combined sources, their respective power inputs need to be managed to balance the load between them.

Here's a demonstration of how synchronizing AC generators works, showing the self-synchronizing effect: https://hackaday.com/2017/07/05/how-do-they-synchronize-power-stations-with-the-grid/

This is what happens with wind turbines for example. Ever notice that turbines in a wind farm spin at the exact same rate? That's because they're synced together with each other, and to the grid they're feeding.

Consider two wind turbines next to each other. One that is 'leading' will be generating, while its neighbor that is 'lagging' will be motoring. The 'lagging' turbine will be forced to catch up to stay in phase, while the 'leading' turbine will be dragged down a bit.

As a system, the turbines are load balanced, and set up to be 'leading' the grid slightly so they will be outputting power to the grid.

Let's think even bigger. Large generators like steam turbines or hydro plants serving hundreds of thousands or millions of people [must be carefully synchronized as they are added to the grid](https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/preparing-to-synchronize-a-generator-to-the-grid), otherwise the entire grid can go down.

Nevertheless, even for large plants the process is the same: align phase, frequency and voltage before closing the switch, then manage the generator plant's power input so that it is leading the grid slightly, and thus producing power onto the grid and not motoring.

The introduction of HVDC distribution has made power-sharing somewhat easier. With HVDC, the individual AC sources are first converted to DC with a [big, gnarly inverter that looks right out of science fiction](https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/download-center/books-and-guides/electricity-generation-t-d/power-converters-hvdc), then combined onto a shared HVDC bus and distributed that way to the consumer.

At the consumption side the HVDC is locally converted back to AC as needed, or sent on to another HVDC grid for inter-tie sharing.

HVDC distribution decouples AC phasing, not only between multiple sources, but also between source and sink. With HVDC it's even possible for 60Hz and 50Hz to exchange energy, via the shared HVDC bus and DC inter tie. Producers and consumers on an HVDC bus need only manage their voltage to control power flow.

At a slightly smaller scale than inter-tie, some wind and solar farms use a local HVDC bus to combine their energy. ABB for example has a system called [HVDC Light](https://new.abb.com/news/detail/4224/evolution-of-hvdc-lightr) that is used for offshore wind power systems.

Which brings us to the inverter linking a microgrid to a utility feed. Again, grid synchronization is a must, otherwise excessive currents will result (and your utility will get really mad at you.) The inverter senses grid voltage and phase, then connects to it. Inverter currents in or out are monitored carefully, and the inverter's phase and voltage adjusted dynamically to synchronize it to the AC grid, just like the turbines do.

Again, like the turbines, if the inverter is 'lagging' it is consuming power; if it's 'leading' it is producing power. Controlling lead/lag is the basic mechanism it uses to determine power flow.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQrIhK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The reason you don't get 220V is that the incoming AC supply and the inverter(s) are wired in parallel, not series.  If your supply is 110V 60Hz, then the inverter will also put out 110V 60Hz, synchronised to the supply.

Most of the time the inverters spend synchronizing is actually self-testing and then checking that the incoming AC supply is stable and within specification.

Comment: I added a thought experiment to my question to address your answer. I think there's more to it than this. One way or another, the solar power needs to feed the grid. That requires a _voltage potential_ _into_ the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the issues is that you are comparing how Home wiring works to get 240V AC, compared to your Solar production coming in.
A house uses a Split Phase transformer, so a Single Phase from the Utility Company is used to generate two Separate Lines of 120V, these are EXACTLY 180 degrees out of phase and since they come from the SAME source they are EXACTLY the same Frequency.
Some may argue whether this is Two Phase power, it is NOT.  Two Phase is a definition and the Voltage is 120 degrees out.  Split Phase is still a SINGLE Phase SOURCE.  When you bring in power from an External Source, you can NOT just add it to the Home Power.  It has to be IN SYNCH, same Frequency, same Phase, or a 180 Degrees out to get 240V.  It is why those systems have special electronics to manage that.  It's tricky!

[image]